# Read from excel file error

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to read a row from an Excel file.
For some reason, I get an error when I try to read integer values (ID Column).

What the code does is reading information from the Excel file 
and subsequently storing it.

In `UserInfo` implemented as array.
[(Excel File Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMHyW.png)

It throws this error: [ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq4iT.png)

```
   class UserInfo
   {
           public int ID { get; set; }
           public string firstName { get; set; }
           public string lastName { get; set; }
           public string IDNumber { get; set; }
           public string email { get; set; }
   }


    private void openExcelFile(string excelFile)
    {
        UserInfo[] user = new UserInfo[2];
        label1.Text += "Initalize Excel Application And Reading Data";
        ///Read From Excel File And Store in array
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
        _Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        //Start to read from row 2
        for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            user[i - 2] = new UserInfo();
            Range range1 = xlWorksheet.Rows[i];
            user[i - 2].firstName = range1.Cells[i, 1].Value2;
            user[i - 2].lastName = range1.Cells[i, 2].Value2;
            user[i - 2].ID = range1.Cells[i, 3].Value2; //Error
            user[i - 2].email = range1.Cells[i, 4].Value2;
        }

        label1.Text += "Done!\nStart Sql Process:\n";
        //Cleaning GC,Dealing memory
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        //close and release
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any empty **ID** columns in your excel file? It looks like you are trying to convert an empty cell value to int

Comment: No I'ts not empty look in the excel file if you don't believe me (:

Comment: does values are coming from excel sheet to range object?

Comment: Yes @MidhunMundayadan

Comment: Does it coming as null or value.update the connection string what u are using

Comment: Just a "side suggestion": if you want to simplify your code dealing with Excel from C#, consider to use a c# library like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). This way you haven't to deal with Interop, inter-process operations, unmanaged objects, GC, Marshalling, etc.

Comment: What do you mean? @MidhunMundayadan

Comment: I will keep that in mind for next project@MassimilianoKraus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error I encountered before is it could be the data type of that particular cell is not a int so it can't convert the data of that cell to an int.
You can try to use the example below as a workaround:

```
Range r = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A3","F3");
int d;
if (r.Cells[3, 5].Value2 != null) 
{
    var c = r.Cells[3, 5].Value2.ToString();
    d = Convert.ToInt32(c);
}
else
{
    d = 0;
}
```